# How to add group by to eloquent query after unionAll in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to convert this Mysql code to Laravel Eloquent

```
select service_id, sum(cnt) from 
(
    select * from 
    (
        select service_id, count(*) cnt from prdouct_notifs 
        join products on products.id = prdouct_notifs.product_id 
        where prdouct_notifs.user_id = 268 
        and prdouct_notifs.deleted_at is null 
        and prdouct_notifs.block = 4 
        group by service_id
    ) first_table 

   union All
   (
       select service_id, count(*) cnt from products
       where products.pro_user_id = 268
       and products.status = 47575 
       group by service_id
  )
) total_union group by service_id
```

I changed this code to Laravel Eloquent.

```
$get_product = Product::where('pro_user_id', 268)
    ->where('status', 47575)
    ->groupby('service_id')
    ->selectRaw('service_id ,count(*) cnt');

$get_final_product = prdouct_notifs::join('products', function ($join){
    $join->on('products.id', '=', 'prdouct_notifs.product_id')
        ->where('prdouct_notifs.user_id', 268)
        ->where('prdouct_notifs.block', 4);
})
    ->selectRaw('service_id ,count(*) cnt')
    ->groupby('service_id')
    ->unionAll($get_product)
    ->get();
```

**the question is how to run groupby after unionAll**

That's what I want to changed into eloquent.

```
total_union group by service_id
```

Comment: Do you really need to group by service_id in the sub queries? As long as you have all the results, you can surely group and count later

Comment: You can group the collection after retrieving it. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 4):

My idea is to put the UNION into a sub query before grouping. I hope this answers to your question.

```
$product = DB::table('products as p')
    ->where('p.status', 47575)
    ->select('p.service_id as service_id');

$productNotify= DB::table('prdouct_notifs as pn')
    ->select('pn.service_id as service_id')
    ->union($product);

$groupby = DB::query()->fromSub($productNotify, 'p_pn')
    ->select('service_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))
    ->groupBy('service_id');
```

Which produce the following SQL

```
select "stud_id", COUNT(*) as total_asset from (
   select * from (select p.service_id as service_id from products as p) 
   union 
   select * from (select pn.service_id as service_id from prdouct_notifs as pn) 
) as p_pn 
group by service_id
```